# Combining UV maps with textures

Tags: texturing, uv

I am currently trying to import a model into Tabletop Simulator, which requires it to be in one combined piece. I want it colored as well, so I need to make a texture image that will work.

I've tried the join method, but the UV maps (which are all the same name) merely overlap each other. This makes getting a texture image difficult. I've already got textures for each individual piece, so I'm trying to combine them in a way that will work. Is there any way I can keep the layouts for each UV map the same while keeping them all separate on the same UV map, that way I can just combine my already prepared texture images in a way that keeps the coloring the same as when separate?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it is no difference whether have the objects joined or not. While having all the objects selected, you can display and modify all of the objects UV Maps *(check they have the same name)*. However, when only one UV map is allowed, no overlapping can occur.

Later on, when all UVs are placed accordingly, I would export the *UVs* *(UV -> Export UV Map)* and align the textures with the map.

I think this way is the easiest, if you can use Photoshop for example.